# Dropping array into HTTParty API call argument throws `args.ids.split is not a function` error. How do I fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a function called `value` that returns this array below:

```
[1893, 1724, 257344, 353491, 301337, 305470, 348, 264660, 76341, 68726]
```

However for more clarity, here is the `value function` that returns the `value array` above: It's a module like `ListInfoService` below and has 4 arguments which are the arguments supplied in the values method below `ValueSearchService::ValueSearch.new(params[:one], params['two'] = 1_000_000, params[:three], params[:four]).values`

```
def value
    params = set_params_if_not_added
    value_search = ValueSearchService::ValueSearch.new(
      params[:one],
      params['two'] = 1_000_000,
      params[:three],
      params[:four]
    ).values
    value_search['data']
  end
```

I also have a function where the argument `ids` is supposed to take the result of value (i.e. comma separated numbers):

```
module ListInfoService
  class ListInfo
    include HTTParty
    base_uri 'localhost:7000'

    def initialize(ids, limit, offset)
      @options = { query: { ids: ids, some_params: some_params, another_params: another_params } }
    end

    def movies
      self.class.get('/list', @options)
    end
  end
end
```

The URL I interpreted to make the module function above is:

```
localhost:7000/list?ids=2,3,6&some_params=5&another_params=0
```

But when I call the function by dropping `value` result into the function call below, I get `args.ids.split is not a function` error:

```
list_info = ListInfoService::ListInfo.new(
   value,
   params[:some_params],
   params[:another_params]
).movies

render json: list_info
```

So how do I make sure my `ids` argument takes a comma-separated list of number?

**Note**: Am using HTTParty, Rails5.1, Ruby 2.6

I think the problem is the array `value` that I supplied inside `ListInfoService::ListInfo` that searches an api. If I can probably change how I call my api in the module or find a way to supply comma-separated list of ids needed, it will work.

Comment: `args.ids.split is not a function` is an ECMAScript error, not a Ruby error. This error message comes from some piece of ECMAScript code that you are not showing us.

Comment: I don't have any other code am not showing. Am calling this from Postman and that's what returns.

Comment: I have a function called value that returns this array below: could you show your function value

Comment: Edited and supplied that function

Comment: The error message is a JavaScript error. It doesn't come from Ruby code. No matter how much Ruby code you add to your question, we cannot tell you where the JavaScript error comes from.

Comment: I don't understand except HTTParty Gem which I am using to call the API is using JavaScript. But that's not enough to flag my question down. I will try and fix it. Again, I don't have JS in my RAILS API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. This is what I have done to make this work. Bear in mind this error is thrown as a result of passing an array into the HTTParty API call argument. Hence the `args.ids.split is not a function` Error.

Fixing this for me is just by converting the `value` to `string` instead of `array` by just adding `.join(', ')` to the response in the method. See below:

```
  def value
    params = set_params_if_not_added
    value_search = ValueSearchService::ValueSearch.new(
      params[:one],
      params['two'] = 1_000_000,
      params[:three],
      params[:four]
    ).values
    value_search['data'].join(', ') # This will solve it.
  end
```

Thereby when you append `value` result to the defined HTTParty module call to the `ids` argument, it takes it as a string and it works fine.

```
list_info = ListInfoService::ListInfo.new(
  value, # Note that this line is `ids` under ListInfoService::ListInfo argument and cant be array.
  params[:some_params], 
  params[:another_params]).movies 

render json: list_info
```